# JupyterHub JupyterLab - ImportError: cannot import name 'AsyncKernelManager' from 'jupyter_client.manager'

Tags: python, kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I have been running JupyterHub under k8s in notebook mode but want to switch to JupyterLab now. When I launch JupyterLab first I am asked to rebuild the kernel (which fails) so I then rather don't rebuild. Next:

When I try to launch a python3 kernel, in the logs (JS console and on the container backend) I get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'AsyncKernelManager' from 'jupyter_client.manager'
```

If I open a terminal from inside JupyterLab and execute

```
python -c "from jupyter_client import AsyncKernelManager"
```

there is no problem.

How on earth to proceed?

PS There is an open github ticket on this here - without much information https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_client/issues/551

Answer (score 2):

Did you update anything in the root conda environment after launching the container? This happens to me if the python version is updated (potentially due to reading from different libraries).

Comment: This was my problem. Close jupyterlab, reopen in new bash  solved it.